# Create em tabela relacionada com outra tabela não funciona

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Estou com problemas para inserir em duas tabelas relacionadas, as tabelas Peoples e Addresses.

A inserção está sendo feita apenas na tabela Peoples.

A relação na tabela Addresses e feita entre o **'id'** de Peoples e **'peoples_id'** de Adresses. Ou seja uma relação de um para muitos.

Os dados de request são obtidos de um formulário que contém tanto os campos de People quanto de Address.

**Código da classe People**

```
class People extends Model
{


    protected $fillable = [
        'photo', 
        'name', 
        'email', 
        'phone',
        'tel', 
        'nationality',
        'naturalness', 
        'birth_date', 
        'cpf', 
        'sex', 
        'rg', 
        'marital_status', 
        'election_title',
        'election_section', 
        'electoral_zone', 
        'dad_name', 
        'mother_name',
    ];

    protected $table = 'peoples';

    public function address () {
        return $this->hasMany(Address::class, 'people_id');
    }

}
```

**Código da classe Address**

```
class Address extends Model
{
       protected $fillable = [
        'people_id',
        'cep', 
        'uf', 
        'country',
        'city', 
        'district', 
        'public_place', 
        'number_home',
        'complement',
    ];

    protected $table = ['addresses'];

    public function people () {
        return $this->belongsTo(People::class, 'people_id');
    }

}
```

**Código do controlador:**

```
    public function store(Request $request, People $modelPeople,  Address $modelAddress)
    {

        $modelPeople->create($request->all());

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No model `Address` a propriedade `$table` recebe uma string, estás a definir um array..

Tenta assim:

```
protected $table = 'addresses';
```